# intersect two nested arrays

Tags: plsql

Following code gives "PL/SQL: ORA-00907: lack of right bracket".
Why?

```
select count(*)
into v_cnt
from (table(v_A) intersect table(v_B));
```

While

```
select count(*)
into v_cnt
from table(v_A);
```

Compiles without problems.
v_A is of type t_A created by:

```
create or replace type t_A is table of varchar2(1 byte);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first intersect the two result sets and then count the elements, like this:

```
   select count(*)
   into   l_cnt
   from 
      (
         select * 
         from   table(v_A) 
      intersect 
         select * 
         from   table(v_B)
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in PL/SQL, you should probably use [`MULTISET INTERSECT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators006.htm#i1035636).

It's simpler and several orders of magnitude faster than using SQL.

Normally it is much simpler and faster to use SQL.  But in this case, since you're already in PL/SQL, the opposite is true.  You want to avoid switching between them when possible.

```
--SQL Method: 8.5, 8.455, 8.502 seconds
--PL/SQL Method: 0.015, 0.016, 0.016 seconds
declare
    v_cnt number;
    v_a t_a := t_a('a','b','c');
    v_b t_a := t_a('a','b');
    v_c t_a;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
        --SQL method
        /*
        select count(*) into v_cnt
        from 
        (
            select * from table(v_A) 
            intersect 
            select * from table(v_B)
        );
        */

        --PL/SQL method
        v_c := v_a multiset intersect v_b;
        v_cnt := v_c.count;
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_cnt);
end;
/
```